# Oracle SQLPlus: Select statement, where (?) and order by

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm writing an extensive paper and as part of having coded tables and inserted values into them I was given some questions I have to answer; but one of them I'm having a lot of trouble with so I'm hoping one of you guys could help me out! The question is as follows:

> Show the book_copies, currently checked out, that were overdue on 10-OCT-2014.  The output will show bookid, copy_num, customer last name and first name, num of days overdue (no negative or zero for this column!).  Order by bookid, copy_num.  PLEASE, DO NOT update the balance_due in this question.

Book_copy table:

```
create table BOOK_COPY
(Copy_Num number(5),
Bookid  number(5),
out_to_CID number(6),
Date_Out date,
Date_Due date,
Held_Until date,
held_for_CID number(6),
CONSTRAINT PKCOPY PRIMARY KEY (Copy_Num,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT FKCID FOREIGN KEY (out_to_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKHeld FOREIGN KEY (held_for_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKBookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK (Bookid));
```

Customer table:

```
create table CUSTOMER
(CID number(6),
First_Name varchar2(12),
Last_Name varchar2(12),
Category varchar2(7),
Balance_Due number(4,2),
SponsorID number(6),
CONSTRAINT pkCID PRIMARY KEY (CID),
CONSTRAINT fkCUSTOMER foreign key (sponsorID) references customer);
```

Comment: Ha, welcome. Sadly no one here will solve homework for you. Post how far you have gotten and what specific part you have trouble with, and we may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you! Well though I am aware this isn't for doing students' homework, it sure seems judging from a lot of other questions that I am not the only one asking for it - I am just the only one not pretending it isn't. Anyway, I understand where you're coming from but I figured I'd rather be honest about it :-)

Comment: @NiTre, you misunderstand. We don't disallow homework questions; what Sabeeh is rightly saying is that you have to put some effort into it *before* asking the question. In this case, Sabeeh has really helped you, but the answerers below have NOT helped you (but with good intentions, I'm sure) because they've just given you the answer on a silver platter. But, it's your education to waste if you want.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Sorry for the delayed answer (didn't get an e-mail back then, but thought I'd answer you anyway since you made an effort).
So... I also get where you're coming from, and I agree with you. As I probably should have elaborated earlier the two tables - book_copy and customer - were all a product of my work, and I had already done most of the assignment by that time... Yes, I got the answer on a silver platter, as you point out, but from the point I was on back then I was really stuck, and hints or tips instead of a full answer would have been just as helpful (if not more)! :-)

Comment: Well, in fact the problem with your question is that it doesn't actually ask a question - it merely states "the question is as follows" followed by a problem statement. You never asked for hints or tips, merely implied that you wished someone to solve your problem for you. I'm voting to close because in its current format, this question will not help anyone else.

Comment: Alright, I see your point there. Should definitely have formulated a question as to what I exactly was having a problem with in this case so to make it clear for others how to give hints without just giving away a full answer. I disagree with you that others can't find help from this answer though, since I'm sure other rookies have had and will have problems that reminds of this one - but I respect your opinion. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in seeing how many days it is overdue from October 10 you can use this bit of code instead:

```
select
bookid,
copy_num,
Last_Name,
First_Name,
Date_Due - to_date( '10-OCT-2014') total_days_overdue
from
book_copy bc
inner join customer c on bc.out_to_cid = c.cid
where
Date_Due >'10-OCT-2014'
Order by
bookid, copy_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner join, subtracting one date from another would look like this:

```
select
  bookid, 
  copy_num, 
  Last_Name, 
  First_Name, 
  Date_Due - sysdate total_days_overdue
from
  book_copy bc
  inner join customer c on bc.out_to_cid = c.cid
where
  Date_Due > to_date('20141010','yyyymmdd')
Order by 
  bookid, copy_num
```

Comment: That's a big help, thank you. I'll see if I can make it work or modify it to!

Comment: @NiTre, Homework is not offtopic (see [help/on-topic]) but it does say `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`  So make sure to do that next time.

Comment: Downvoter, please rate the answer rather than the question.  If you see a problem, please comment.

Comment: It appears you've just given away the answer to a homework question. That encourages people to just come dump low quality questions on the site without putting any effort in. They won't learn that way, and the quality of the sites goes down. A better approach would be to hint at the proper path to take, or encourage them to make an attempt and then help correct their attempt.

Comment: @mason, you may be interested in [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/2589202) on this topic.

Comment: I am sorry that this turns out to be a problem for you, paqogomez, that wasn't my intention. And I'll make sure to do so next time, if there is to be one. I have used Stackoverflow before but never by asking questions so I guess I didn't do my homework properly (ehe ehe) before posting this question. Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: You can take the discussion to meta if you want. My downvote is staying, for many of the reasons already described in that meta discussion.

Comment: @NiTre, its not a problem.  Its a hard business posting to SO for the first time.  Its a skill you learn.  You'll get better, just like you'll get better with sql.

Comment: @mason, that is your prerogative.